# Write to json file in increments of 50

Tags: node.js

I am currently looping through a json object with the purpose of writing certain key value pairs to a new json file. I can write all the elements in the newVideos array to a new file. However, I need to get the first 50 and write it to a file, then the next 50 and so on... Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
async function GetVideos(videoData) {
var videos = videoData.videos;

var newVideos = [];
for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {

    var o = videos[i];
    newVideos[i] = {
    ID: o.ID,
    Videos: o.Videos
    };
}
```

}

Comment: just use `i % 50 == 0` as an if statement.